# New to the Scrapy library, how do I troubleshoot an empty JSONL file while web scraping?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Spider not doing its job scrapy

i tried to run the folllowing scrapy spider to scrap and parse a website and put the results in a jsonl, which stays empty, im new to the libary

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

from fitness.fitness.items import FitnessItem

class Silva(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "silvaspider"
    allowed_domains = ['https://weighttraining.guide/exercises/']
    start_urls = ["https://weighttraining.guide/exercises/"]

    def parse(self, response):
        for h1 in response.css("h1::text").getall() :
            yield FitnessItem(name=h1)
        for muscle in response.css("li::text").get() :
            yield FitnessItem(muscle_groups=muscle)
        for href in response.xpath("//a/@href").getall():
            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(href), self.parse)


process = CrawlerProcess(
    settings={
        "FEEDS": {
            "items.jsonl": {"format": "jsonl"},
        },
    }
)

process.crawl(Silva)
process.start()
```

Comment: what is it you are expecting this code to do?